# How to construct Vedi?

Tags: yajna

Vedi or Havan kunda is the place or figure inside which holy fire or yagyagni is lit. My  question is how many type of vedi's are possible? and what are its technical specs which should be followed while building it? Can a copper utensil (also known as tamra vedi or tamrakunda) be used for small yagnas?
[This](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/inr/product/sculptures/havan-kund-ZBG03/?gclid=COjO9Lbjl8gCFVcPjgodwy4CJg) is what tamrakunda looks like

Comment: Building an altar isn't a simple undertaking.  Look at this chapter of the Shatapatha Brahmana, for instance: http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe43/sbe4363.htm. The configurations are described in great detail in the various Shulba Sutras.  And there's a ritual you have to do while building the altar; for instance, you have to chant the Chamakam as you're laying bricks, as described in Prapathaka VII of this Kanda of the Taittiriya Samhita of the Yajur Veda: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv04.htm